# Decrease the value of the variable containing the current time with UISlider

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I don't know how to make the current time value (returned by the dateFormatter variable) change when scrolling the slider.
I tried to convert the dateFormatter variable to double but without success.

```
var c: Double
c = Double(dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

I would like to decrease the value of the time -1 hour for each shift of the slider thumb.
The changeTime function has to take care of changing the time value when moving the slider.

```
@IBOutlet weak var sliderTime: UISlider!
@IBOutlet var labelTime: UILabel!
var timer = Timer()
var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
override func viewDidLoad()
{
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        labelTime.text = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimeLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
}

@objc func updateTimeLabel() {
      labelTime.text = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
}

 @IBAction func changeTime(_ sender: Any) {
      
 }
```

Comment: This is a little unclear... *"decrease the value of the time -1 for each shift"* Do you mean by -1 **seconds**? or **days**? And by *shift* do you mean when the user drags the slider thumb?

Comment: You are right, sorry!
I meant to decrease by 1 hour on each slide of the thumb slider

Comment: What is the min/max value of your slider?

Comment: Notice that you change the time label every minute, so even the slider changed it, it will be changed the next minute with the current date?

Comment: @andreaghezzi - try to think through your question a little more. By default, a `UISlider` has a min value of 0 and a max value of 1, and sliding the thumb changes that value between the min and max. So, if I slide the thumb to 0.38, or 0.72, or 0.94, etc ... what's supposed to happen?

Comment: @EssamMohamedFahmi I didn't understand the question.  If you answer, I'll answer you in a few hours, ok?

Comment: @DonMag the min value is 0 and the max value is 10. If you answer, I'll answer you in a few hours, ok?

Comment: Okay, you will have 11 integer values from 0 to 10, you want to decrease the current time based on the slider value, right?

Comment: @DonMag if I scroll to 0.38 then the value must be decreased by 0.62

Comment: @EssamMohamedFahmi yes. I will probably change those values, but now I just need to understand how I can proceed to change the time based on the slider.

Comment: I can get the integer value from the slider so that any change in the slider will give you an integer number: 0, 1, 2, 3, ... 10, then you can decrease the time by this value, will this work for you?

Comment: I understand that if the slider value should be an integer and if it is 5 then the current time should be decreased 5 hours , right?

Comment: @andreaghezzi - ok... since you are a beginner, the first step is to read the docs and go through a couple tutorials on using a `UISlider`. Then next step is to read the docs and go through a couple tutorials on modifying a `Date` object. Once you've done that, you'll have answered your own question. But asking how to do *something* without knowing anything about it is a waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5

Whenever you update the date, decrease the number of hours dedicated by slider from the current date, try this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var simpleSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

    var timer = Timer()
    var currentSliderStep: Int = 0
    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
       dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
       labelTime.text = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
       timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimeLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
    }

    @objc func updateTimeLabel() 
    {
       let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -currentSliderStep, to: Date())!
       labelTime.text = dateFormatter.string(from: newDate)
    }

    @IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let value = simpleSlider.value
        let step: Float = 1
        let roundedValue = round(value / step) * step
        currentSliderStep = Int(roundedValue)
    }
}
```

> Note: With the Slider, the "Primary Action Triggered" event is triggered when it is adjusted. This is the perfect event to handle (link this event to `sliderMoved`).